# Connection to a Python API from my Android device without entering the address

Tags: python, android, flask, ip-address

I've created a simple Python API with Flask, and I can easily access it from my Android studio inserting as host 10.0.2.2.

The problem is when I want to access the API server from a physical Android device.
In fact I want to access the API without entering the IP address of the PC, since it changes time by time.

Any clue?

Comment: If you can't (or don't want to) use an IP address you'll need to use DNS to map a hostname to an IP address. And if the IP address isn't static (i.e., it changes over time) then you'll need to dynamically update the DNS record.